# Will the same JavaScript fetched by HTTP and HTTPS be cached separately by the browser?

Tags: tls, web-application, web-browser, http, same-origin-policy

Say that a web server supports both HTTP and HTTPS. If a browser fetches the same JavaScript with a HTTP GET and a HTTPS GET, and the JavaScript is cache-able, will the browser cache two copies of the same JavaScript?

The reason I'm asking is that if only one copy is cached, would it be possible for an attacker to first trick the victim into downloading JavaScript via HTTP and compromise it along the way, which will result in a cache poisoning attack?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Resources are cached by their URL, and the protocol (`http://` or `https://`) is part of the URL. Since the protocol differs, the URL must also differ, and you have two separate cache entries.

Answer (score 46):

It is perfectly fine if a `http://` and a `https://` resource provide different data, even if everything but the access method is the same. For example access to `http://` will today often result in a redirect response while access to `https://` provide the real content.   A browser will therefore cache these resources independent from each other.

Comment: Following your lead, if ```http://example.com/example.js``` is redirected to ```https://example.com/example.js```, and ```example.js``` is finally fetched, will this script be cached under ```http://example.com``` or ```https://example.com```?

Comment: Depending on the exact response code and `Cache-Control` headers, the `http:…` response will be cached as a redirect.  The cache entry for the `https:…` response will then separately store the actual JS.  On subsequent requests for `http:…`, the browser will check its cache, see a redirect, and then begin a request for the redirect target -- possibly without sending any bytes over the network.  In your scenario, the browser would look for the `https:…` JS, which it may serve directly from cache also or go to the network.  The above may also be modified by HSTS.

Comment: I do not think this answers the question: are these resources handled as equal in cache?

Comment: @Daan: resources are cached by the URL which was *directly* (i.e. no redirect in between) used to request the cached resource. This means these resources have different cache entries.

Comment: Theoretically, you could express that the locations are equivalent using `Content-Location` or `Location` headers, and then a cache would be allowed to treat them as the same. I do not know if any common implementations actually do this.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica A user agent's cache is based on the _request_, not the _response_. That might include caching _the fact that the result was a redirect_, but that is not the same as _considering the two URIs as equivalent_. In particular, the relationship is one-way: if resource A redirects to resource B, then a change to resource A won't have any effect on the cache for resource B.

Comment: @IMSoP Sorry, I meant `Link`, not `Location`. No redirects are involved. A user agent's cache behaviour is very much determined by the response headers.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica If a response could cause a user agent to consider two resources as equivalent, that would in itself be a huge security problem. Consider if I write a page at `https://example.com/whatever` that claims, in whatever way you like, to be "equivalent to `https://apple.com`"; then later, I change that page to instead serve malicious content. If the browser simply merged the two cache entries, I could overwrite the user's cache of `https://apple.com` with my malicious content. The response can _narrow_ the cases where a cache is valid, but it cannot _widen_ it.

Comment: @IMSoP yes, doing it across origins would certainly be insecure

Answer (score 8):

Summary:

- The primary cache key for any standards-compliant browser is an absolute URI
- The absolute URI begins `http:` for all insecure requests and `https:` for all secure requests
- Consequently, a resource fetched securely can never use the same cache key as a resource fetched insecurely

---

The current standard for HTTP is split across multiple "RFC" documents, with [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) dedicated entirely to caching, because there is a lot of complexity involved.

In section 2, "Overview of Cache Operation", there is this summary:

> The primary cache key consists of the request method and target URI.
> However, since HTTP caches in common use today are typically limited
> to caching responses to GET, many caches simply decline other methods
> and use only the URI as the primary cache key.

This is more formally stated in the first bullet point in section 4, which says:

> When presented with a request, a cache MUST NOT reuse a stored
> response, unless [...] the presented effective request URI (Section 5.5 of RFC7230) that of the stored response match [...]

[Section 5.5 of RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.5) starts by saying

> For a user agent, the effective request URI is the target URI.

A browser is a "user agent", so this is the case we're concerned with here. "Target URI" is defined [in section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.1):

> A URI reference (Section 2.7) is typically used as an
> identifier for the "target resource", which a user agent would
> resolve to its absolute form in order to obtain the "target URI".
> The target URI excludes the reference's fragment component, if any,
> since fragment identifiers are reserved for client-side processing
> (RFC3986, Section 3.5).

The generic definition of a URI is in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), and HTTP-specific concerns take up three pages of RFC 7230. The most relevant part for our purposes is [RFC 3986 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3) which defines this grammar for Absolute URIs:

> absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]

Crucially, note that `scheme` is a mandatory part of any Absolute URI. Since HTTP URIs always use the scheme `http` and HTTPS URIs always use the scheme `https`, this means that their absolute URIs, and thus their "primary cache keys" in a browser, can never collide.

---

Other answers have mentioned ports. [RFC 7230, Section 2.7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1) defines `http` URIs as including an "authority" section, which is defined in [RFC 3986, Section 3.2]:

> authority   = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]

The port is optional, with [RFC 7230, Section 2.7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1) defining the default for the `http` URI Scheme:

> If the port subcomponent is empty or not given, TCP port 80 (the reserved port
> for WWW services) is the default.

And the following section defining the default for "https":

> All of the requirements listed above for the "http" scheme are also
> requirements for the "https" scheme, except that TCP port 443 is the
> default if the port subcomponent is empty or not given, and ...

It then follows that:

- Any HTTP request not on port 80 must include a port number in its absolute URI
- Any HTTPS request not on port 443 must include a port number in its absolute URI
- No two requests with different port numbers specified will have the same cache key, since they will have distinct absolute URIs

Thus these URIs would all be cached separately:

- http://example.com/some/resource (default port 80)
- https://example.com/some/resource (default port 443)
- http://example.com:8000/some/resource (non-default port)
- https://example.com:8000/some/resource (non-default port)
- http://example.com:443/some/resource (insecure request on port normally used for HTTPS)
- https://example.com:80/some/resource (secure request on port normally used for plain HTTP)

The only thing I'm not clear on is whether the browser should, may, or must normalise URIs which explicitly mention the port which would be the default anyway. In other words, whether these two URIs would be cached separately or not:

- http://example.com/some/resource
- http://example.com:80/some/resource

I can't think of any practical consequence of normalising these to the same cache key, because by the definitions above they are guaranteed to represent the same resource.

Comment: [RFC 7230 section 2.7.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-2.7.3) and [RFC 3986 section 6.2.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-6.2.3) make it pretty clear that browsers _may_ normalize `http://example.com:80/path` to `http://example.com/path`, but seem to stop short of saying that they _must_ do so for the purposes of caching.

Comment: I did some quick testing.  Firefox, Safari, and Chrome all normalize the URL for all purposes.  Edge normalizes the URL for caching, but not for display purposes.  Internet Explorer is...odd (I couldn't get consistent cache behavior out of it regardless of URL).

Comment: In addition to having the absolute URI in the key, browsers will be adding the origin of the top frame into the key as well (called double-keyed caching). This is to protect against XS-Leaks. Safari already had double-keyed caching (but slightly differently) for a while. https://www.jefftk.com/p/shared-cache-is-going-away

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Given that caching is optional to begin with, it seems natural that they only require to differentiate between things that may refer to different resources, while they do not require to necessarily identify all cases of equal resources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because they are different network destinations. The tcp port is not shown in the location bar when using the standard port.

Http defaults to tcp port 80. Www.example.com:80

Https defaults to tcp port 443
Www.example.com:443

Even if the domain and ip are the same, the ports are not. From the browser perspective, the browser is communicating with different sites.

**UPDATE**

The network doesn't affect it as much as the S does in the https. It's a different URI, too.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line here say "yes", if it's to answer the title? (yes, I realise that the question contains some rephrasing of the title with reversed sense to the title question).

Comment: Thank you!. I guess it is the same case at the CDN and reverse proxy level?

Comment: This appears to be wrong. If the caching happened at TC/IP level, you would have issues with SNI (Server Name Indication). Multiple sites can share the same TCP/IP.

Comment: I am 99% sure that caching is keyed on _URIs_ ("Uniform Resource Identifiers"), not network connections. If there was some scenario where HTTP and HTTPS were served on the same port, the two requests would still be distinct, because they are requesting different resources, with different URIs.

Comment: I agree with @IMSoP, at least web browser cache is based on URL. What I am not certain is if protocol HTTPS/HTTP or port 443/80 are considered cache key, and if this behavior is consistent for all browsers and intermediate caches(CDN or reverse proxy).

Comment: I'm downvoting because you're right for the wrong reasons.  It's not the port (implicit or otherwise) that makes an HTTP address distinct from an HTTPS address, it's the protocol.

Comment: @Mark no, `http://www.example.com:80` is also a different URI (and thus not cache-equivalent) to `http://www.example.com:8080`

Comment: @Mark: Well, no, this answer is exactly correct. I would argue that the port is the primary discriminator, though it wouldn't surprise me if a browser _also_ discriminated on protocol (when the port is, for some weird reason, and defying logic, the same)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Caching is an HTTP-level concept, not a network-level one, and defined in terms of URIs, not network destinations. The port is relevant _only because of its interaction with URIs_. I've just posted an answer with full references, so we don't need to speculate.

Comment: @IMSoP We never needed to speculate, because it's plainly obvious - see StopHarmingMonica's example. But I'm glad that the references you've found back this up. :)

Comment: @IMSoP I'm actually not sure what you were saying in your comment. Sure, a URI doesn't _have_ to describe a resource that's on a network. But, nobody claimed that it did.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I meant we don't need to speculate about whether it's the port or the scheme that makes a difference, or how different browsers might work, we can look it up in the spec. And the answer is that the scheme is always part of the URI, so will always make a different cache entry, regardless of anything to do with ports. The mention of "network-level" was referring to the first line of this answer, which incorrectly states that the cache will vary "because they are different network destinations".

Comment: @IMSoP but it has nothing to do with what's network-level. Both protocol and port are part of the URI. They both make a difference.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica I agree. The question we are commenting under states otherwise.

Comment: @IMSoP Well, if they're different network destinations then they have different URIs ;) But, if we're to nitpick a bit, I agree that the statement is perhaps misleadingly narrow. Anyway I think we're all fundamentally in agreement.

Comment: Let's say HTTPS was implemented by some sort of `STARTTLS` style or `Upgrade` header procedure on port 80. Would that make `https://example.com:80/` equivalent to `http://example.com:80/` ?

Comment: @curiousguy no, those URLs are still different

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the fact that the spec is quite clear that different URLs should be treated as different resources, don't you think that someone might have noticed and exploited this by now if it were not the case? After all the issues exposed by cookies (and addressed by the "secure" flag) have been known about for 20 years or more.

So the browser must retrieve both URLs. It is conceivable that a cache might retain a single copy of a file downloaded from different sources but accessed via different keys - or that this de-duplication might occur deeper in the filesystem (de-duplication). But this would only happen *after* the cache (or the filesystem) had determined that the files were the same.

Comment: Well, thanks for your comment, but I can't agree on your first point. Most security vulnerabilities seemed "simple" only after someone found it. For me, I just happened to think this point and curious how it really behaves in practice.

Answer (score 0):

From a server-side perspective the same URL (eg. www.test.com) on different protocols (eg. HTTP vs HTTPS) can use a different file source. So a URL with TLS can output a completely different website than the URL without TLS. This alone makes me think that browsers won't use the same cache for both files.

Comment: This feels like an exact duplicate of [Steffen Ullrich's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/222648/51961).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are different origins. While it's very likely they would serve the same content, they can technically serve entirely different content. For this reason, the browser is not allowed to treat them as the same resource.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't really add anything that other answers haven't already said. It's also problematic to use the word "origin" here, because that has a particular meaning in web technologies, and many URLs can have the same origin but still require completely different cache entries.